# In SQL Server : how to change the value in xml tag before reading from select query

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have written a query to read the data from `Table1`. In that table there are 2 columns which have xml values, so I need to change one of the xml element value with the new value (it doesn’t matter what value is already present)

My query :

```
SELECT [StatusCode]
      ,MethodDetail 
      ,[ExtendedData] 
      ,[PostMarkDate]
      ,[Amount]
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
FOR XML RAW('PaymentRecord'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('Payments')
```

My current result:

```
<Payments>
 <PaymentRecord>
  <StatusCode>ACV</StatusCode>
  <MethodDetail>
            <Check>
              <BankName>JPMORGAN CHASE BANK</BankName>
              <RoutingNumber>0187671</RoutingNumber>
            </Check>
  </MethodDetail>
  <ExtendedData>
            <Extra>
              <Source>Bank</Source>
              <PolicyNumber>12345677            </PolicyNumber>
            </Extra>
  </ExtendedData>
  <PostMarkDate />
  <Amount>648.1000</Amount>
  </PaymentRecord>
</Payments>
```

I need change the `PolicyNumber` element value to my own value like '76576566' - I will not be knowing what value present in the table - but I know new value which needs to be changed.

Kindly let me know how to perform this.

This is the sample table with the data (my current SQL version is v18.11.1):

```
CREATE TABLE [Table1]
(
    [StatusCode] NVARCHAR(10),
    [MethodDetail] XML,
    [ExtendedData] XML,
    [PostMarkDate] DATE,
    [Amount] DECIMAL
)

INSERT INTO [Table1] ([StatusCode], [MethodDetail], [ExtendedData],[PostMarkDate], [Amount]) 
VALUES ('ACV',
        '<Check>
              <BankName>JPMORGAN CHASE BANK</BankName>
              <RoutingNumber>0187671</RoutingNumber>
            </Check>', 
        '<Extra>
              <Source>Bank</Source>
              <PolicyNumber>12345677            </PolicyNumber>
            </Extra>', '',
        '648.1000')
```

Expected Output should be: I just need to display in my select query result with new policy number - no update to the table

```
<Payments>
  <PaymentRecord>
    <StatusCode>ACV</StatusCode>
    <MethodDetail>
      <Check>
        <BankName>JPMORGAN CHASE BANK</BankName>
        <RoutingNumber>0187671</RoutingNumber>
      </Check>
    </MethodDetail>
    <ExtendedData>
      <Extra>
        <Source>Bank</Source>
        <PolicyNumber>76576566</PolicyNumber>
      </Extra>
    </ExtendedData>
    <PostMarkDate>1900-01-01</PostMarkDate>
    <Amount>648</Amount>
  </PaymentRecord>
</Payments>
```

Comment: Your desired output is not matching two rows data in the source table. Do  you need to change the PolicyNumber element value to your own value like '76576566'  for all the rows?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Yitzhak - Thank you for the response, I have corrected my sample table data, I just need to change to new policy number value (which I already have) - kindly let me know how do i do that in my select query - I am  new to sql need your suggestion on this please

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to update this value in the table or just show a different value in your select statement? If you want to update it first, what key would you use to isolate your row?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just need to display in my select query result - no update to the Table

Comment: `ExtendedData.query('<Extra> {for $e in Extra/*
  return if ($e is (Extra/PolicyNumber)[1]) then <PolicyNumber> 7657654321</PolicyNumber> else $e} </Extra>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL #1**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
(
    [StatusCode] VARCHAR(10),
    [MethodDetail] XML,
    [ExtendedData] XML,
    [PostMarkDate] DATE,
    [Amount] DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO @tbl ([StatusCode],[MethodDetail],[ExtendedData],[PostMarkDate],[Amount]) values 
('ACV',
N'<Check>
    <BankName>JPMORGAN CHASE BANK</BankName>
    <RoutingNumber>0187671</RoutingNumber>
</Check>', 
N'<Extra>
    <Source>Bank</Source>
    <PolicyNumber>12345677</PolicyNumber>
</Extra>', 
'',
'648.1000');

DECLARE @PolicyNumber VARCHAR(20) = '76576566';
DECLARE @outXML XML = (
SELECT [StatusCode]
      ,MethodDetail 
      ,[ExtendedData] 
      ,[PostMarkDate]
      ,[Amount]
FROM @tbl
FOR XML RAW('PaymentRecord'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('Payments'));

SET @outXML.modify('replace value of (/Payments/PaymentRecord/ExtendedData/Extra/PolicyNumber/text())[1] with sql:variable("@PolicyNumber")');

-- test
SELECT @outXML;
```

**SQL #2**

```
SELECT [StatusCode]
      ,MethodDetail 
      ,ExtendedData.query('<Extra>{
            for $e in /Extra/*   
            return if (local-name($e)="PolicyNumber") 
            then <PolicyNumber>{sql:variable("@PolicyNumber")}</PolicyNumber> 
            else $e
        }</Extra>')
      ,[PostMarkDate]
      ,[Amount]
FROM @tbl
FOR XML RAW('PaymentRecord'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('Payments');
```

**Output**

```
<Payments>
  <PaymentRecord>
    <StatusCode>ACV</StatusCode>
    <MethodDetail>
      <Check>
        <BankName>JPMORGAN CHASE BANK</BankName>
        <RoutingNumber>0187671</RoutingNumber>
      </Check>
    </MethodDetail>
    <ExtendedData>
      <Extra>
        <Source>Bank</Source>
        <PolicyNumber>76576566</PolicyNumber>
      </Extra>
    </ExtendedData>
    <PostMarkDate>1900-01-01</PostMarkDate>
    <Amount>648</Amount>
  </PaymentRecord>
</Payments>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time both worked perfect. Especially SQL #2 is ultimate.